# Sharepoint 2013 column validation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to do some validation on a list. I can get 2 individual IF statements to work on there own but I can work out how to merge them into one. The two statements are;

```
=IF([Amount deducted before tax]<>"0",IF([Start date before tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

and

```
=IF([Amount deducted after tax]<>"0",IF([Start date after tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Comment: If it is meant to be an "if or if" logic, start with `OR` and put the ifs in there: eg: `=OR(if(),if())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Formulas

```
=IF([Amount deducted before tax]<>"0",IF([Start date before tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

and

```
=IF([Amount deducted after tax]<>"0",IF([Start date after tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

return TRUE/FALSE values, since the IF itself returns a TRUE/FALSE value

You can simplify them to

```
=IF([Amount deducted before tax]<>"0",[Start date before tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE)
```

and

```
=IF([Amount deducted after tax]<>"0",[Start date after tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00",TRUE)
```

Then swap the TRUE/FALSE return (*just so the first parameter of the IF is always the TRUE value*)

```
=IF([Amount deducted before tax]="0",TRUE,[Start date before tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00")
```

and

```
=IF([Amount deducted after tax]="0",TRUE,[Start date after tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00")
```

SharePoint does not have a logical AND *operator*, it does have an AND *function* which takes parameters

So the combined function becomes:

```
=AND(
     IF([Amount deducted before tax]="0",TRUE,[Start date before tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00")
     ,
     IF([Amount deducted after tax]="0",TRUE,[Start date after tax]="01/01/0001 00:00:00")
    )
```

Note: best practice is to built your functions in a text editor, including line breaks and indentation. Then copy/paste to SharePoint. SharePoint will remove all indentation/line breaks on save

More Formulas at:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your help and your explanation.

Comment: Very happy to do so...and this is going to be a silly question I know...how do I accept the answer. I haven't done it before and the process isn't apparent. There doesn't seem to be an 'Accept this answer' button.

Comment: There should be a checkmark icon on the left of the answer